# How can i have only a VIEW(readonly) function in django admin's page where there is a table named X and having some data in it?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a table named X and entered some information into it, now what i want is whenever i clicked on that particular information it is giving an editable form which is not required. If once it is saved i need it to only view my information not to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make some fields read-only while adding a new instance, you can list them under `readonly_fields`

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Also, if you want to make some fields read-only when editing, then you should try this :

```
class AddressModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj: # If object exists, means you're editing one.
            return self.readonly_fields + ('street1', 'street2')
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works fine and i have a query like whether there is any option like edit for a read only fields?If so how can this can be done?